# Filter rows based on a time stamp in another column Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following data frame in Spark Scala:

```
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
 |Index   |                Date|              Date_x|
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
 |       1|2018-01-31T20:33:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T20:35:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:04:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:05:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:15:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:16:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:19:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:20:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       2|2018-01-31T19:43:...|2018-01-31T20:35:...|
 |       2|2018-01-31T19:44:...|2018-01-31T20:35:...|
 |       2|2018-01-31T20:36:...|2018-01-31T20:35:...|
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to remove the rows where `Date < Date_x` for each Index, as illustrated  below:

```
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
 |Index   |                Date|              Date_x|
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:19:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       1|2018-01-31T21:20:...|2018-01-31T21:18:...|
 |       2|2018-01-31T20:36:...|2018-01-31T20:35:...|
 +--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I tried adding a column `x_idx` by using `monotonically_increasing_id()` and getting  `min(x_idx)` for each `Index` where `Date < Date_x`. So that I can subsequently drop the rows from a data frame that don't satisfy the condition. But it doesn't seem to work for me. I probably miss the understanding of how `agg()` works. Thank you for your help!

```
  val test_df = df.withColumn("x_idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
  val newIdx = test_df
           .filter($"Date" > "Date_x")
           .groupBy($"Index")
           .agg(min($"x_idx"))
           .toDF("n_Index", "min_x_idx")

      newIdx.show

      +-------+--------+
      |n_Index|min_x_idx|
      +-------+--------+
      +-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `$` in

```
.filter($"Date" > "Date_x")
```

so the correct `filter` is

```
.filter($"Date" > $"Date_x")
```

You can use `alias` instead of calling `toDF` as

```
val newIdx = test_df
  .filter($"Date" > $"Date_x")
  .groupBy($"Index".as("n_Index"))
  .agg(min($"x_idx").as("min_x_idx"))
```

You should be getting output as

```
+-------+---------+
|n_Index|min_x_idx|
+-------+---------+
|1      |6        |
|2      |10       |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I solely want to remove rows where Date < Date_x for each Index. Maybe my original approach is wrong.

Comment: Thank you once again! Great! I guess I sorted the data frame in a wrong order - that was the problem. Fixing it now.

Comment: great to hear that @vanja_65 :)

Answer (score 0):

The filter condition might filtering all the records. Please check that print the dataframe after filtering records and make sure your filter works as you expected.

```
 val newIdx = test_df
           .filter($"Date" > $"Date_x")
           .show
```

Comment: didn't you see my answer ? @Ravikumar If you see a working answer then you should upvote it . not that you answer the same again. If your answer was different than mine then thats fine but its not different

Comment: Thank you, Ravikumar, for a helpful hint!

Comment: @RameshMaharjan -  Yes I didn't see your answer when I posted the reply.  I was in the middle of answering question, had some other work and posted after some time. If I saw your answer before when I click on submit, why should I reply the same question.